# LaTeX, use czech characters inside of commands

Tags: input-encodings, embedding, attachfile

is there any way to use czech characters (ě, š, č, ř, ž, ý, á, í, é etc.) inside of commands?

I am currently trying to use the `attachfile` package to embed another file in my main file.

I tried using this: `{\v{r}}`, tried multiple packages, also tried using a `\newcommand`, but to no avail.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{calc, attachfile}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,czech]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\newlength{\Urlname}
\newcommand{\doubleprint}[1]{\setlength{\Urlname}{\widthof{#1}}}
\newcommand{\textattachfileandprintout}[2]{%
\textattachfile[color=0 0 0]{#1}{#2}\doubleprint{#2}\hspace{-\Urlname}#2}

\newcommand{\NameOfTheFile}{{\v{r}}}

\begin{document}

\textattachfileandprintout{Bakalářská_práce2.pdf}{linktext}

\end{document}
```

I am using pdflatex to compile.

I am getting this error when trying to compile:

```
Navigace.tex (line 19)
pdfTeX error (ext5): cannot open file for embedding. (...ntout{Bakal√°≈ôsk√°_pr√°ce2.pdf}{linktext} ...)
```

Thanks

Comment: `\textattachfileandprintout{\detokenize{Bakalářská_práce2.pdf}}{linktext}`

Comment: @egreg Oh I see, this makes sense and works perfectly. Thanks, if you can post an answer I would flag it as a solution. Thanks

Comment: Today not as obvious as it was years ago, but another solution is avoid accents in filenames. Easier and still solves a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer from @egreg helped me: `\textattachfileandprintout{\detokenize{Bakalářská_práce2.pdf}}{linktext}`